# How to pass complex JSON Object in URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying pass a complex JSON Object in URL

```
input = { "id": 1, "sd": "123", "filter": { "h": 1,"road": true }, "legs": [{ "id": 1, "x1": -0.001, "y1": 51.122 }, { "id": 2, "x1": -12, "y1": 12 }] };
```

I have tried these functions

```
 data_str = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(input))

 var urlParam = []

 for (var i in input) {
      urlParam.push(encodeURI(i) + "=" + encodeURI(input_[i]));
 }
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'localhost/foo',
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: "json",
         //data: { input: data_str },
         data: { input: urlParam.join("&") },
         success: function (e) {
              alert(e);
         }

       });
```

Comment: Why not just set `data: input`?

Comment: I see you commented out data: {input:data_str}, what if you just set data : data_str. data_str looks like it should be URIncoded correctly

Comment: `input` is a _JavaScript Object_, it is only _JSON_ after `JSON.stringify` before `encodeURIComponent` and _JSON_ is a _String_. The `encodeURIComponent` escapes characters that would have meaning in a _URI_ so you can submit it safely. Your `urlParam` _Array_ is never _JSON_. Once the server receives the _JSON_, it only knows it is a _String_ until you tell it "this is actually _JSON_, parse it please" in the server-side code

Answer (score 0):

I hope this package works for you.
`npm i url-object-converter`

**Convert Object to URL**
use `convertObjectToUrl(yourInputObject)`

**Convert URL to Object**
use `convertUrlToObject(yourInputURL)`