# Javascript Windows.Location pass complex JSON object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I've the following object which I am passing into an MVC Controller:

```
this.JsonData = {
    "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),
    "searchMode": {
        "mode": Number(mode.val()),
        "pageSize": Number(pagesize.val()) || 5,                                       "pageNumber": Number(pagenumber.val()) || 1,                
        "sortField": sortfield.val() || "Ref",
        "sortDirection": sortdirection.val() || "desc"
    },
    "searchData": {
        "Compare": Number(StdComparison.val()),
        "SearchTextFrom": searchText.val(),
        "SearchTextTo": searchTextTo.val()
    }
```

This works ok, but I recent requirement has arisen whereby I am looking to encode this object for use with the javascript function Window.location

Suggestions I have used:

[how-to-pass-complex-json-object-in-url-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153875/how-to-pass-complex-json-object-in-url-using-javascript)

```
window.location + "?SearchCriteria=" + JSON.Stringify(this.JsonData);
```

Creates the following request:

```
Controller/Action?SearchCriteria={
    "__RequestVerificationToken": "tokenvalue",
    "searchMode": {
        "mode": 2,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "sortField": "Ref",
        "sortDirection": "desc"
    },
    "searchData": {
        "Compare": 1,
        "SearchTextFrom": "From A",
        "SearchTextTo": "To Z"
    }
}
```

Whereas

```
window.location + "?SearchCriteria=" + this.JsonData;
```

Produced the following:

```
Controller/Action?SearchCriteria=[object%20Object]
```

With a page not found error on both of the above.

UPDATE:

I have moved forward in the quest for an answer.

OK as per request from helpers, I have included more source code.

I have Three Classes.

```
public class MainSearch
{
    public MainSearch()
    {
        SearchData searchData = new SearchData();
        SearchMode searchMode = new SearchMode();
    }
    public SearchData searchData { get; set; }
    public SearchMode searchMode { get; set; }
    public int? page { get; set; }
    public object ToPagedListParameters(int pagenumber)
    {
        searchMode.pageNumber = pagenumber;
        return page;
    }
    public IList<string> ValidationErrorMessages { get; set; }
}
public class SearchData
{
    // Fields used for the ticket number search
    public int? ticketNumberCompare { get; set; }
    public string ticketSearchTextFrom { get; set; }
    public string ticketSearchTextTo { get; set; }

}
public class SearchMode
{
    public int? mode { get; set; }
    public int? pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int? pageSize { get; set; }
    public string sortDirection { get; set; }
    public string sortField { get; set; }
    public string userURN { get; set; }
    public string __RequestVerificationToken { get; set; }
}
```

These classes hold the criteria used for searching *(SearchData has been truncated)*

The following is my controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFileCSV(MainSearch search)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/") + "somefile.pdf";
    byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    return File(fileContents, "application/pdf", "result.pdf");
}
```

And finally, the Ajax call that is made from the cshtml file.

```
$("#DownloadAttachmentCSV").click(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: JsonData,  
            type: "GET",
            success: function () {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")' + '?' + JsonData;                      
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

Oddly enough, the code above does actually work and the file is downloaded, but here is the problem. The JSON data is not populating the MainSearch variable.

So far the only way I can get the JSON data to populate the c# classes is to change the method to a POST.

Must this be the case?

Comment: You can pass a complex javascript object to a GET method. What is the signature of the method your calling?

Comment: It is using HttpGet on the MVC controller action

Comment: Yes I know - again what is the signature of the method (and if its a model, show that model)

Comment: The signature is: public FileResult MethodName(SearchCriteria data)

Comment: the model is: public class SearchCriteria { public SearchMode searchMode {get;set;} public SearchData searchData {get;set;}}

Comment: Edit your question, not in comments (and show ALL the models including `searchMode` and `SearchData`)

Comment: Where both SearchMode and SearchData are classes with the fields listed in the exmaple code as, an example, public string sortfield {get;set;}

Comment: The reason I have not replied yet, is that I am formulating the required code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass complex javascript objects to a GET method like that. A GET has not body and to bind to a model, your query string name/value pairs must match the properties of the object your binding to. For example to bind to the `mode` property of the `SearchMode` property of `MainSearch`, you query string would need to include

```
....&SearchMode.mode=2....
```

Change the code your using to generate the javascript object to

```
var data = {
    'searchMode.mode': mode.val(),
    'searchMode.pageSize': pagesize.val() || 5,
    'searchMode.pageNumber': pagenumber.val() || 1,
    'searchMode.sortField': sortfield.val() || "Ref",
    'searchMode.sortDirection':  sortdirection.val() || "desc",
    'searchData.SearchTextFrom': StdComparison.val(),
    'searchData.Compare': searchText.val(),
    'searchData.SearchTextTo': searchTextTo.val(),
}
```

and the ajax code to

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")' + '?' + $.param(data),
        type: "GET",
        success: function () {
```

Note also the following

1. There is no point using `Number(..)` to convert the values to a
   number - its all sent across the wire as text
2. A GET has no body so setting the ajax `contentType` option is
   pointless
3. Your method does not return json so `datatype: 'json'` does not make
   sense.
4. Passing the antiforgery token to a GET method is not necessary

Having said that, its unclear what your wanting to do here. The code in your `MainSearch search()` method never uses any values of the model. And it returns a `FileResult` which cannot work with an ajax call (but it can work with `window.location`, it which case the code in the success callback would need to be

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")';
var queryString = $.param(data);
window.location = baseUrl + '?' + queryString;
```

but then its unclear why you making 2 calls to the method - the ajax call, followed by the redirect (the ajax call does nothing at all).

Answer (score 2):

Anything you use as a query parameter should be properly URI encoded, especially with something like JSON:

```
window.location + "?SearchCriteria=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.JsonData));
```

I'm not sure that the model binder is designed to convert JSON in a GET request into a class instance, but the attempts you've made above are definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Stringify i must to write it in lower case, like this: `'&json=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @Oscar Thanks. looks like I had a typo.