# Making HTTP Get call from Ajax to an MVC Controller, parameter is a complex Json object shows as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three classes

```
public class MainSearch
{
    public MainSearch()
    {
        SearchData searchData = new SearchData();
        SearchMode searchMode = new SearchMode();
    }
    public SearchData searchData { get; set; }
    public SearchMode searchMode { get; set; }
    public int? page { get; set; }
    public object ToPagedListParameters(int pagenumber)
    {
        searchMode.pageNumber = pagenumber;
        return page;
    }
    public IList<string> ValidationErrorMessages { get; set; }
}
public class SearchData
{
    // Fields used for the ticket number search
    public int? ticketNumberCompare { get; set; }
    public string ticketSearchTextFrom { get; set; }
    public string ticketSearchTextTo { get; set; }

}
public class SearchMode
{
    public int? mode { get; set; }
    public int? pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int? pageSize { get; set; }
    public string sortDirection { get; set; }
    public string sortField { get; set; }
    public string userURN { get; set; }
    public string __RequestVerificationToken { get; set; }
}
```

The following is my controller code:

```
  [HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFileCSV(MainSearch search)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/") + "somefile.pdf";
    byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    return File(fileContents, "application/pdf", "result.pdf");
}
```

And finally, the Ajax call that is made from the cshtml file.

```
  $("#DownloadAttachmentCSV").click(function () {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: JsonData,  
            type: "GET",
            success: function () {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadFileCSV", "Home")' + '?' + JsonData;                      
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

The code above does actually work and the test file, somefile.pdf, is downloaded.

My question:

In the controller, I am expecting the MainSearch object to be populated. This is currently not happening. On checking the classes SearchData and SearchMode are set as null.

How can I fix this?

Sorry, forgot to add the Json.

```
      var JsonData = {
            "searchMode":
                {
                    "mode": "1",
                    "pageSize": "5",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "sortField": "PodRef",
                    "sortDirection": "desc",
                    "userURN": "3175",
                },
            "searchData":
                {
                    "ticketNumberCompare": "1",
                    "ticketSearchTextFrom": "From A",
                    "ticketSearchTextTo": "To Z"
                }
        };
```

Comment: have you tried `data: { "search": JsonData }`?

Comment: Yes I have and it does nothing

Comment: I've just realised that you appear to be calling the same action method twice (once via Ajax, and once via window.location). Why is this? Surely only the second call is required. And for the second one, you can't submit JSON data like that directly into the querystring. You'd be better to serialize the object.

Comment: It's a quirk of Ajax calling an MVC controller action that returns a file. Please see link           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704078/how-to-download-a-file-through-ajax-request-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Windows.Location pass complex JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364825/javascript-windows-location-pass-complex-json-object)

Comment: @gilesrpa that answer is wrong IMO. I can't see any need to use ajax at all for this. Just call window.location directly. All you're doing is making two trips to the server instead of one. And the first one basically has no purpose, because you don't do anything with the response. When you call window.location, it makes the same request all over again and downloads the file again. Stephen's suggestion is relevant, however - use $.param() to encode the data on the querystring.

Answer (score -1):

use JsonProperty with both Model Like:

```
public class SearchData
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ticketNumberCompare")]
    public int? ticketNumberCompare { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ticketSearchTextFrom")]
    public string ticketSearchTextFrom { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ticketSearchTextTo")]
    public string ticketSearchTextTo { get; set; }
}
```

and use a view model Like

```
public class JsonData
{
    public SearchMode SearchMode{get;set;}
    public SearchData SearchData {get;set;}
}
```

and use like that at action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFileCSV(JsonData search)
{
    string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Pdf/") + "somefile.pdf";
    byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    return File(fileContents, "application/pdf", "result.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Dharmesh, unless I have missed something, this does not work, I have changed my code to match the above. Do I need to change the ajax call in any way?

Comment: you need to change from  data: JsonData to  data:JSON.stringify({ JsonData: JsonData })

Comment: this doesn't address the fundamental issue that a) ajax is unnecessary in this situation, and b) the call to window.location is not working because you can't pass raw JSON on the querystring. See the suggested duplicate answer.